# DOS Batch that sends email via outlook

Tags: windows, batch-file, outlook

I'm getting trouble with my batch file. Everything work from command prompt but won't work as a batch

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\outlook.exe" ^
  /c ipm.note /m "someone@domain.com&subject=FTP details&body=Hello,%0D%0APlease ^
    find x WAV's (24bit, 48kHz cut to the first frame of picture.) I have ^
    uploaded them onto the FTP site available for download, as requested.^
    %0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ahttp://ftp.tjg.co.uk/%3FCommand=Logout%26user=user%26password=pass"
```

Comment: swapping %0D%0AP, %3F, %26 for some c:\1111111.test.bat :) but when I type this to command prompt then works well

Comment: Echo your command to a file and see what you get. You'll probably need to escape your &'s and double your %'s